# IE file download box get location

Tags: file, internet-explorer, download

i am currently working on a issue where i need to get location of the file downloaded.First let me explain the scenario.

I placed a link in my page and when user clicks the link it shows file download dialog with open/save/cancel options in IE.Now when the user clicks on the save button and choose a location to save the file i need to get that file saved location using whatever options possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply avi and Gung Foo.

Comment: i have a doubt in activexobject how can i save text files in my documents folder in windows(by using OpenTextFile()) because if the user is not an admin then i don't think saving the file in location like C:/ is valid since he may not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can... at least not easy. This runs on the client, and for security reasons you can not acces the client's filesystem  with javascript.

Maybe it is however possible using a flash or silverlight plugin, as the user can allow access from within these applications to the local filesystem. It might be very difficult tho...

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not allow you to access information about the clients filesystem.

Comment: not even with any browser settings.I just need to know about IE.Thanks for the reply!